# Subquery returned more 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql

In the following query i m getting 'Subquery returned more 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression' error

```
SELECT  MemberID,
        FirstName,
        MiddleName,
        LastName,
        (FirstName+' '+LastName) AS FullName,
        Gender,
        CASE    Gender
        WHEN    1 THEN  'Male'
        ELSE    'Female' END AS GenderName,
        Phone1,
        MemberNumber,
        MembershipTypeID,
        (   SELECT  MembershipTypeName
            FROM    MembershipTypeMaster
            WHERE   MembershipTypeID    =   MemberDetails.MembershipTypeID ) AS MemberType,
        (   SELECT  MaxCreditLimit
            FROM    MembershipTypeMaster
            WHERE   MembershipTypeID    =   MemberDetails.MembershipTypeID ) AS MaxCreditLimit,
        (   SELECT  DepositAmount
            FROM    MemberCreditInfo
            WHERE   MemberID    =   MemberDetails.MemberID ) AS DepositAmount,
        Phone1,
        Phone2,
        Mobile,
        EMail,
        HouseNumber,
        City,
        MemberDetailsState,
        (   HouseNumber+','+City+','+MemberDetailsState+','+PinCode ) AS Address,
        PinCode,
        MemberPhoto,
        MemberStatus,
        ISNULL((    SELECT  ( MaxCreditLimit - UsedCredit )
            FROM    MemberCreditInfo    
            WHERE   MemberID =  MemberDetails.MemberID ),0) AS BalanceCredit,
        ISNULL((    SELECT  UsedCredit
            FROM    MemberCreditInfo    
            WHERE   MemberID =  MemberDetails.MemberID ),0) AS BalanceToPay
  FROM  MemberDetails
  WHERE MemberStatus <> 99
```

Comment: How is this quesion related to CSS3, javascript or jquery?

Comment: This is SQL query and nothing to do with the above tags

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not spam but  should be closed

Comment: @ColdFire Yeah, I think you're right. Already voted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about on of your inner select queries.

For example if the following query returns more than one result sql cant know what should it write to MemberType cell.

```
( SELECT  MembershipTypeName
        FROM    MembershipTypeMaster
        WHERE   MembershipTypeID    =   MemberDetails.MembershipTypeID )
```